# Using Exponential Shift to find general solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have these 2 theorems/definitions.

*For each natural number n,
$(D-m)^n e^{mx} y = e^{mx}D^ny$

*If f(D) is a polynomial in D with constant coefficients then
$e^{mx}f(D)y=f(D-m)e^{mx}y$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
where $D^n y= {d^ny\over dx^n}$

Now, we have this example, 
$ (D-2)^3y=0$
and this how my teacher solved it,
$$ \begin{align}(D-2)^3y=0 \\
   e^{-2x}(D-2)^3y=0 \\
   D^3(e^{-2x}y)=0 \\
   D^2(e^{-2x}y)= c_1 \\
   D(e^{-2x}y   = c_1x+ c_2 \\
       e^{-2x}y = {c_1x^2 \over 2} + c_2x + c_3 \\
               y= ({c_1x^2 \over 2} + c_2x + c_3)e^{2x}
\end{align} 
 $$

My question is how come she multiplied the second line by $e^{-2x}$ and not by $e^{2x}$. If we look at the above theorems/definitions and $m=2$ from the example, we have to multiply the second line by $e^{2x}$ and not by $e^{-2x}$ to use that theorem above. Please enlighten me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $e^{-2x} (D-2)^3 y \neq (D-2)^3 e^{-2x} y$, since $(D-m)^n$ is a differential operator which *acts* on $y$ or $e^{-2x} y$.
Probably, sometimes it is better to write $(D-2)^3 (e^{-2x} y)$ to reflect this action and not to be confused.

(For example: $e^{-x} Dy \neq D(e^{-x} y)$, since $D(e^{-x}y) = -e^{-x} y + e^{-x} Dy$)

To understand how to apply the theorem above to the equation $(D-2)^3y=0$, I would suggest you to make a simple change of variables: let $y = e^{2x} u$.

Then, you will get
$$
0 = (D-2)^3 (e^{2x} u) \underbrace{=}_\text{by theorem} e^{2x} D^3 u.
$$
Hence, $D^3 u = 0$, and therefore
$$
u = \frac{c_1}{2}x^2 + c_2 x + c_3.
$$
Finally, $y = \left(\frac{c_1}{2}x^2 + c_2 x + c_3\right) e^{2x}$.